# Create link to specific blog article by primary key in Django and slugify url

Tags: django, slug

I am following some basic tutorials to learn the basics of building websites in Django.
I have a "news template" working, but I am struggling to (understand) create the links to a specific database article and use the slug in the url. I have only managed to find examples where a list of all posts are shown with links but this is not what I am looking for.

I have this:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    text=RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug=slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={"id":self.id, "slug":self.slug})
```

views.py

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('articles/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    # path('articles/<slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail')
    
    ]
```

html:

```
 <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=1 %}">'*article headline from post.title (somehow)*'</a>
```

This works when I hardcode the primary key of the article but of course the url shows with the pk and fails if I try using slug (NoReverseMatch).

What can I do in the html line to be able to point to a specific article but get the slugfield to be shown in the url? (I dont mind putting in the pk manually if the other stuff works)

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

views.py

```py
def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

urls.py

```py
#...

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/<slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

HTML

```html
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"> ... </a>
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I pass the pk in the html line? This dont throw any errors but it wont link to anything? I am not using a list of all post, and I don't know how to link to a specific post without hardcoding the primary key

Comment: Share your view that renders the HTML, so we can see how you're passing the post obj

Comment: I am hard coding the pk in the html line like this:

`<a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=1 %}">'*article headline from post.title (somehow)*'</a>`


and in views:

`def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})`

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting, don't know how to format code properly in comments